# Spring Boot configuration from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, configuration, war

I see that the values in application context are not getting picked up when the Spring Boot project is war file and runs on an external Tomcat.

How do I resolve this issue?

Example - `server.port=8096` but the port when loaded is still 8080

Comment: Please provide the relevant code snippets from your application.

Comment: The `server.*` properties only apply to an embedded container NOT when deployed to an external tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to move the properties file outside of your project. The application.properties under src/main/resources will remain but referencing the external properties file. For e.g.

```
spring.config.location=./tomcatfolder/external-application.properties
```